# Can't start Elasticsearch anymore

Tags: macos, elasticsearch, homebrew, kibana

After making a simple change on a query in Kibana, my Elasticsearch instance stopped working and I can't start it up again. I'm using ES 0.90.9 on OSX using homebrew.

Normally I would use this to start ES:

```
elasticsearch -f -D es.config=/usr/local/opt/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
```

This however throws out a repeated error:

```
[2014-04-07 15:59:02,123][INFO ][node                     ] [Puck] version[0.90.9], pid[8758], build[a968646/2013-12-23T10:35:28Z]
[2014-04-07 15:59:02,128][INFO ][node                     ] [Puck] initializing ...
[2014-04-07 15:59:02,224][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Puck] loaded [mongodb-river, mapper-attachments, marvel], sites [river-mongodb, marvel]
[2014-04-07 15:59:04,553][INFO ][node                     ] [Puck] initialized
[2014-04-07 15:59:04,553][INFO ][node                     ] [Puck] starting ...
[2014-04-07 15:59:04,665][INFO ][transport                ] [Puck] bound_address {inet[/127.0.0.1:9302]}, publish_address {inet[/127.0.0.1:9302]}
[2014-04-07 15:59:07,727][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Puck] new_master [Puck][gtub58OkR9SskDE0SfYobw][inet[/127.0.0.1:9302]], reason: zen-disco-join (elected_as_master)
[2014-04-07 15:59:07,778][INFO ][discovery                ] [Puck] elasticsearch_dannyjoris/gtub58OkR9SskDE0SfYobw
[2014-04-07 15:59:07,795][INFO ][http                     ] [Puck] bound_address {inet[/127.0.0.1:9202]}, publish_address {inet[/127.0.0.1:9202]}
[2014-04-07 15:59:07,796][INFO ][node                     ] [Puck] started
[2014-04-07 15:59:07,813][INFO ][gateway                  ] [Puck] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
[2014-04-07 15:59:09,589][ERROR][marvel.agent.exporter    ] error connecting to [localhost:9200]
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:382)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:241)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:228)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:431)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:527)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:158)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:424)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:538)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:214)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:300)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:319)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:987)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:923)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:841)
    at org.elasticsearch.marvel.agent.exporter.ESExporter.openConnection(ESExporter.java:313)
    at org.elasticsearch.marvel.agent.exporter.ESExporter.openConnection(ESExporter.java:293)
    at org.elasticsearch.marvel.agent.exporter.ESExporter.checkAndUpload(ESExporter.java:428)
    at org.elasticsearch.marvel.agent.exporter.ESExporter.checkAndUploadIndexTemplate(ESExporter.java:464)
    at org.elasticsearch.marvel.agent.exporter.ESExporter.checkAndUploadAllResources(ESExporter.java:341)
    at org.elasticsearch.marvel.agent.exporter.ESExporter.openExportingConnection(ESExporter.java:190)
    at org.elasticsearch.marvel.agent.exporter.ESExporter.exportXContent(ESExporter.java:246)
    at org.elasticsearch.marvel.agent.exporter.ESExporter.exportNodeStats(ESExporter.java:134)
    at org.elasticsearch.marvel.agent.AgentService$ExportingWorker.exportNodeStats(AgentService.java:274)
    at org.elasticsearch.marvel.agent.AgentService$ExportingWorker.run(AgentService.java:174)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
[2014-04-07 15:59:09,591][ERROR][marvel.agent.exporter    ] Could not connect to any configured elasticsearch instances: [localhost:9200]
```

Comment: The error you mentioned does not mean that your elasticsearch node is not working but only that it could not contact your Marvel node. Why do you think it's not working? Could you also paste your elasticsearch.yml file?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? I am encountering the same problem, Marvel cannot connect.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the plugins directory worked for me.

The location of the plugins directory can be found in your config file under the path.plugins setting. e.g.

`# Path to where plugins are installed:
path.plugins: /usr/local/var/lib/elasticsearch/plugins`

You can find default plugin paths [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-dir-layout.html#default-paths)

This should not destroy your marvel data, but I guarantee nothing.